# How to add 'features="html.parser"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, code-formatting

```
response = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
rows = bs.find('table', {'class': "infobox"}).find_all('tr')
list1 = []
for i,tr in enumerate(rows):
  cells = tr.find_all('td')
  if len(cells) == 2:
    list1.append(cells[0].text.strip(":"))
    list1.append(cells[1].text.strip('\n'))
res_dct = {list1[i]: list1[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(list1), 2)}
print (res_dct)
```

In the line, `rows = bs.find('table', {'class': "infobox"}).find_all('tr')` where could I add the features="html.parser?

Comment: Add it when creating the`soup` object `bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser' )`

Answer (score 0):

You should add it here:

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
```

So it looks like this (based on your code):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
rows = bs.find('table', {'class': "infobox"}).find_all('tr')
list1 = []
for i, tr in enumerate(rows):
    cells = tr.find_all('td')
    if len(cells) == 2:
        list1.append(cells[0].text.strip(":"))
        list1.append(cells[1].text.strip('\n'))
res_dct = {list1[i]: list1[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(list1), 2)}
print(res_dct)
```